# How to make Windows Explorer report the correct size of the winsxs folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, winsxs

I know that the files inside the winsxs folder are not copies but low-level hard links. They look like the full file, but really it's just a shortcut. For this reason, the folder is not taking up as much space as Windows Explorer says it is, because it's double counting that data.

Windows Explorer reports a size of **11Gb**. Git Bash and the MS-DOS command prompt report 11Gb as well. However, If I dual boot into Ubuntu and check the size in a terminal with `du -h`, or with the Baobab tool, it reports a size of **7.9Gb**, which I guess is the real size of my winsxs folder.

So, my question is, is there a way to tell my Windows system that the folder is just 7.9Gb?

Answer (score 0):

This difference is caused because one tool counts only file sizes, and the other counts real space occupied by these files and directories.

Here you can read about "clusters":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster

In short, when you have 4-kilobyte clusters on your system (and you probably have), then even 1-byte file occupies whole cluster, which is 4 kilobytes. This article will further explain this difference.

Comment: Yes, my cluster size is 4Kb. But my question was... is there a way to tell Windows that the size of that folder is 7.9Gb, so that it shows the correct size in the "My Computer" folder, and shows the correct size when I click a folder's Properties as well? I don't want a tool that shows the correct size "to me", but something to tell "the system" the correct size. Does that make sense or is it possible at all? P.S. Also, I'm not sure cluster size is the only reason of incorrect size reporting for this particular folder.

Comment: There is also another reason, why reported size is incorrect: algorithm used in Properties tab and in many more places, counts only files and subdirectories, which are "visible" for user executing such algorithm. So if you don't have right for some directory, then nothing inside it won't be counted. However this can only decrease the visible size, not increase, so I didn't mention it in the answer.